# Django: ModuleNotFoundError. No module named 'myApp'

Tags: django, modulenotfounderror, termux

I am using termux
I created a virtual environment, started django project, cd into the second directory of my project, and started an app.
 [Here is the arrangement of my dir. and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X49GT.jpg)

I added the app to the INSTALLED_APP in setting.py
[INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRPn6.jpg)

When I run 'python manage.py runserver, I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError. No module named 'myApp_name'
[Error message after running 'python manage.py runserver'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTPjY.jpg)
Please help me resolve this issue. I am a beginner and have been on this for two days I am stuck and can't learn further.

I expect 'python manage.py runserver' to run without an error, since I started an app and added its name to INSTALLED_APP

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you overwrite every call / project, app name in the `settings.py` and `apps.py` files?

Also check if the app was created correctly or is not under additional subdirectory.